# Amazon EC2 Linux Permissions with Magento 2

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, magento2, php-7

I have a Amazon AWS EC2 installation with vhosts file setup and StartCOM SSL Certificate. I have run through the installation setup passing the Magento Readyness checks completing the installation with success.  I can access the Magento Administrative area without a problem, but the storefront loads with an Error 500.

I believe this to be a permissions problem, but require some assistance with troubleshooting and correcting the problem.

- 4.4.15-25.57.amzn1.x86_64
- Apache/2.4.23 (Amazon)
- PHP Version 7.0.9
- Magento 2
- /var/www/html/magento/

  `grep
  apache /etc/group
  ec2-user:x:500:apache
  apache:x:48:`

  `ls -l
  total 1004
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache 130922 Aug 21 09:59 access_log
  drwxr-sr-x  4 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:41 app
  drwxr-sr-x  2 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:41 bin
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache 434798 Jun 23 09:41 CHANGELOG.md
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache   1843 Jun 23 09:39 composer.json
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache 340876 Jun 23 09:41 composer.lock
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache   3381 Jun 23 09:41 CONTRIBUTING.md
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache    631 Jun 23 09:41 COPYING.txt
  drwxr-sr-x  5 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:41 dev
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache    408 Aug 21 09:32 error_log
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache   2854 Jun 23 09:41 Gruntfile.js.sample
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache   1358 Jun 23 09:41 index.php
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache    315 Jun 23 09:41 ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md
  drwxr-sr-x  4 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:41 lib
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache  10376 Jun 23 09:41 LICENSE_AFL.txt
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache  10364 Jun 23 09:41 LICENSE.txt
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache   5233 Jun 23 09:41 nginx.conf.sample
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache   1427 Jun 23 09:41 package.json.sample
  -rw-r--r--  1 root apache    804 Jun 23 09:41 php.ini.sample
  drwxr-sr-x  2 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:41 phpserver
  drwxr-sr-x  6 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:41 pub
  drwxr-sr-x  7 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:41 setup
  drwxr-sr-x  7 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:39 update
  drwxrwsr-x 11 root apache   4096 Aug 21 09:59 var
  drwxrwsr-x 29 root apache   4096 Jun 23 09:41 vendor`

Comment: Turns out, after eight or more hours of trying and reading that it was a typo "httpss" (double ss).  I still however need to correct these permissions for the site.

Comment: Did you read this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: That is a Magento 1.x document. Not Magento 2

Comment: Yes just read the permission part it applies for Mag 2 too.

Comment: NOT AT ALL HELPFUL. Your advice is FAR off the mark and left my server now offline.